# "Two forms attached to the email": is "attached" a verb or an adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, passive-voice, reduced-relative-clauses

Could you please let me know that the "attached" is a 'verb' or an 'adjective' in the sentence given below.

> Please print the two forms **attached** to this email.

If possible then please give a justification.

Comment: @CopperKettle is spot-on, the only thing I would like to add to it is, "attached" is a 'verb' and an 'adjective' in the sentence under question, that is why it is a *participle*. A participle is a special case where a verb is used as an adjective and the verb "attached " is used as an adjective here.

Comment: + [interesting post](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/143663/48335) by Jowhn Lawler on "adjectives vs. participles"

Comment: + Wikipedia [on 'stative passives'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Stative_and_adjectival_uses)

Comment: A related question: ["This is allowed" - is this passive voice?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170620/this-is-allowed-is-this-passive-voice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please print the two forms attached to this email.

You can say that the use of "attached" in the sentence can  be regarded both as an adjective and a verb.

Please look at the following sentences to know how it's possible:

1. Please print the two forms which are attached to this email.
2. Please print the two forms which have been attached to this email.

According to grammar, you can simplify or reduce the defining clause, among others, in the following cases:

1. If it contains be + adjective phrase (It applies to the sentence #1).
2. if it contains be + past participle (passive form) (sentence # 2 above).

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses

Comment: Thank you Khan for replying...but mostly I have seen that an adjectives use before noun, here in this sentence it has been used after noun that is why I was in confusion, so apart from is there any place where adjective can be used. (Like after noun, before noun, etc...). IF it is there I request you to let me know.
Also please let me know is the correct or not?

Please print the attached two forms in this email.

Comment: @CharmiSapariya "Please print the **two attached** forms": the word **two** is a *determiner*, and we put it first, next come adjectives like **attached**.

Comment: "both......or?" How about "either....or?" (or "both....and" if you mean it's simultaneously an adjective and a verb.)

Comment: @brian Hitchcock, both means not only ...but also ..(Oxford). Either ...or..is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> Please print the two forms **attached** to this email.

It is a form of a verb called *past participle*. The sentence contains a [reduced relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause) "*attached to this email*".

The full sentence is either

> 1. Please print the two forms that **are attached** to this email.

or, as Khan wrote,

> 2. Please print the two forms that **have been attached** to this email.

In case of (2), **attached** is clearly a past participle. In case of (1), I'm not sure what it is. According *[to this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/170965/48335)*, it's sometimes hard to distinguish.

It could be seen as a [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) construction, in which case **attached** will be a past participle:

> The forms **are attached** to this email **by me**. I attached them. Please print them.

You cannot use the adverbs **very** and **too** which you usually can use with adjectives:

> Please print the two forms that are **very** attached to this email. (WRONG: the meaning changes drastically)
>
> Please print the two forms that are **too attached** to this email. (WRONG: the meaning changes drastically)

On the other hand, we can try substituting **are** with **seem, look, remain**, and it seems to work:

> Please print the two forms that **seem | remain** attached to this email. (seems OKAY to me; it's one of the "tests" for adjectival predicative complements; or is it WRONG? Should there be "that seem **to be** attached?)

We can try adding the negation prefix **un**:

> Please print the two forms that are **unattached** to this email. (? I'm not sure if this works)

In the end, I'd call it a past participle, a form of a verb, but I'm still not very sure.

Comment: Thank you CopperKettle... Regarding Adverbs and Adjectives usage, you mean to say jointly we cannot use Adverb and Adjective in Passive voice or something different.

Comment: @CharmiSapariya - you're welcome! We can use an adverb to modify an adjective (very attached) but in our case the word *attached* is not an adjective: it's a past participle. You cannot use an adverb to modify a past participle. "These newspapers are (**very**) sold" would sound strange with **very** included, for example. (0: